# Identity involving representing a vector from $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a complex number.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to understand how to get from ($6$) to ($7$) in the excerpt below. Note that this is from a fluid dynamics paper, and $\zeta$ is the vorticity (the $k^{\text{th}}$ component of $\nabla\times\vec{u}$). It's treated as a function here, but for my purposes we can just assume it's constant.

> [image]

What I'm not able to do is to explicitly show that $w^{\prime} = \psi_{y_0} + \psi_{x_0}$, which should be true, by equation ($3$). Here is my attempt:

\begin{align*}
\psi_{x_0} &= \frac{\zeta}{4\pi}\int \int \frac{2(x_0-x)}{r^2} d\mathbf{x} \\
&= \frac{\zeta}{2\pi}\int \int \frac{(x_0-x)}{r^2} d\mathbf{x} \\
\psi_{y_0} &= \frac{\zeta}{2\pi}\int \int \frac{(y_0-y)}{r^2} d\mathbf{x}
\end{align*}

where $r^2 = (x_0-x)^2 + (y_0-y)^2$

And then by differentiating and multiplying by the conjugate of the integrand:

\begin{align*}
w^{\prime}(z_0) &= \frac{-i}{2\pi} \int \int \frac{1}{z_0-z} d\mathbf{x} \\
&= \frac{-i}{2\pi} \int \int \frac{1}{x_0-x +i(y_0-y)}*\frac{x_0-x + i(y-y_0)}{x_0-x + i(y-y_0)} d\mathbf{x} \\
&= \frac{-i}{2\pi} \int \int \frac{x_0-x +i(y-y_0)}{r^2} \\
&= \frac{\zeta}{2\pi} \int\int \frac{(y-y_0) + i(x-x_0)}{r^2} \\
&= -\psi_{y_0} -\psi_{x_0}
\end{align*}
So unfortunately I have $w'(z_0) = -\psi_{y_0} -\psi_{x_0}$, which is off by a sign.

I've n-tuple checked this so many times, and I still cannot see where the error is. Can anyone spot it? Or is there a more fundamental misunderstanding going on?

Comment: Aside 1: In general, $\zeta$ can't be moved out of integral. Aside 2: double integrals are `\iint` not `\int\int`. Compare $\iint$ and $\int\int$.

Answer (score 0):

I did the calculations myself; indeed, the formulas $\nabla \psi = (-v, u)$ and $w' = u-iv$ are inconsistent. You did drop $i$ in the computation, the result should be 
$$
w' =  - \psi_y - i \psi_x
$$
A quick way to check this is to consider the potential of delta-function at $0$, so that $\psi(x_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\log|x_0|^2$ and $w(z_0) = \frac{-i}{2\pi} \log z_0$. Then 
$$\nabla \psi(x_0) = \frac{x_0 }{2\pi|x_0|^2}$$
and
$$w'(z_0) = -\frac{i}{2\pi z_0} = -\frac{i \overline{z_0}}{2\pi |z_0|}$$
In real notation, $-i \overline{z_0} = -i(x-iy) = -y - ix$, hence the result.